# Google Domains forward a server website and don't change browser url bar

Tags: dns, domain-masking, website-hosting, domain-forwarding

I have a DigitalOcean server with a website that is accessible from an IP with a port (ex. http://102.231.92.192:5000, this is not the real url but an example) and I have a Google Domain (ex. domainExample.com).

I am trying to make it so that if a user navigates to the Google Domain URL, the URL accesses the website from the server. On Google Domains I have forwarded a subdomain, used a custom name server, and have followed all instructions from [DigitalOcean's guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-point-to-digitalocean-nameservers-from-common-domain-registrars).  However, when I try navigating to the Google Domain URL in browser, the page redirects to the raw server url (I type in "domainExample.com" in the browser and the page switches to "102.231.92.192:5000", correctly displaying the content. However, I want the page to not redirect and keep "domainExample.com" in the address bar.)

Basically my end goal is being able to do the following with a Google Domain:

User types in "domainExample.com" in the address bar

The content from the site on "102.231.92.192:5000" appears, and the url in the address bar remains "domainExample.com", with no ip or port.

Comment: same problem, do you remember how you solved?

Comment: Did you find a solution?